# Changing public key of someone to read and change messages that are encrypted to him

Tags: public-key-infrastructure

If I am able to change someone's public key, is it possible to alter the key to later read and change his encrypted messages in an easy way? Just remember I don't have his private key.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that's not how assymetric cryptography works. You don't encrypt messages with your own public key unless only you want to be able to decrypt it.

However, if you had access to the public keys of the victim's contacts on their system, you could theoretically change them to be your public key, in which case you would be able to decrypt all messages that were incidentally encrypted using your public key. You could then try to modify the message and reencrypt it using the public key of the original recipient. However, without the victim's private key, you would not be able to sign the message as them, so it may be clear that the message didn't come from who it claims to be.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing.  I think there is an interesting attack scenario involving swapping out someone's published public key.

If Bruce is trying to send a private message to Alice and he looks up her public key on her blog, his message is only private to Alice if the public key hasn't been manipulated.  If Charlie compromises the blog and replaces the Alice public key with his own, any encrypted message that Bruce sends could be intercepted and decoded by Charlie.

You could imagine this in the real-world with the NSA manipulating the Wikileaks public key.

Answer (score 0):

No. The public key and the private key are generated as a pair - as soon as you change the bit you have, it no longer decrypts messages encrypted with the other part. Doesn't really matter if you have the public or private key in this case.

You can, as @korockinout13 says, attempt to get people to encrypt messages to your victim using a public key that you generated, and have the corresponding private key for, in which case you could read the messages, and your victim could not. However, you would have to replace any pre-existing copies of the public key that the sender had, and there might be a bit of a clue that something was wrong if your victim sent a message signed with their own private key that the recipient couldn't verify (because you've changed the public key associated with your victim).